# How to use query builder to select range of waypoints?

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, query-builder

If I have a range of waypoints (x,y coordinates) in an attribute table, what is the best way in query builder to select a range of those points? I would also like to delete the selected points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this I used the auto increment tool to give all of the way points a unique ID, I'm sure there is a more eloquent way of doing this but it worked for me. After that I used the field calculator tool within model designer and used this equation: array_contains(generates_series('0','32'), $id). This gave all of the points between 1 and 32 the ID of 1 and all of the other points 0. After that use the 'Extract by Attribute' tool to designate the field that has the unique IDs, then select the value you want and it should generate just the points you specified in the previous steps.